# Popup at arbitrary location on ViewBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl that is basically a ViewBox inside a Grid with a Border. The ViewBox has a background image and I blit various little icons onto the image. The icons are nothing more than pixels painted onto the background image. In code-behind I can detect when the mouse stays within the bounds of on one of these icons for more then 500ms. I call this a 'hover event'.

When I detect a hover event, I need to pop up something that shows details unique to the object represented by the icon. These details are not just text, there could be images of small graphs, so I think the popup needs to contain a StackPanel. I would like it to pop up, via some slick animation, at a location I specify near the location where the pointer is hovering.

Can someone please show me how to 1) create a popup containing a StackPanel at any given location in the ViewBox and (optionally) 2) have the popup use some slick animation when it appears?

Comment: Just make a custom tooltip template from the default one that will suit your needs and apply that tooltip style to your buttons.

Comment: There are no buttons at design time nor run time. Based on where the pointer is on the ViewBox, I arbitrarily decide where and when I need the popup to appear.

Comment: Eh, buttons = icons sorry. As for your arbitrary choice of where they appear, do you mean they'd appear potentially elsewhere away from those elements? As for when, well you can handle that with tooltip too. The animation part is generally simple, but understanding the loosely defined arbitrary requirements makes it difficult to answer definitively.

Comment: Well, the icons are not buttons... they are only some pixels blit'ed onto the background image of the ViewBox. As the mouse moves around, I check to see if it's location falls within the bounds of any of the icons. If the pointer stays within the bounds of one of the icons for 500ms, I call it a 'hover event' and I need to popup a little window with  information in it unique to the icon being hovered over. This information isn't just test, it could have small graphics, thus the need for the StackPanel.

Comment: I dunno man, still sounds like it's getting made overcomplicated. Your icons, regardless of blit'd or not would still be objects in the tree right? Which I can't imagine listening for timed pointer location events when you could just attach a tooltip (tooltipservice) with an `InitialShowDelay` of your 500ms, and still "pop-up" your `StackPanel` or whatever with a slick animation with your unique info, etc etc. Just my two cents mate.

Comment: Maybe I am do it the wrong way, I am experienced at winforms and often think the wrong way about things in WPF. In my case I have a map as a background image. At runtime I am provided a collection of modules in a tree control. The user drags the modules from the tree to the map and drops them. I blit an icon at that location on the background image. I keep a collection of modules that have been dropped on the map. I can check the pointer location against that collection pretty fast and use a DispatcherTimer to detect hover. If you were doing this, what would you do when a module was dropped?

Comment: I wish SO had like a meeting scheduler type functionality to meet up for a chat for instances like this. We're getting to enough comments I'd normally suggest we take it to chat but I've got a meeting in 5 and another couple after lunch so I'll have to disappear on ya for a bit, but I think I could offer an easier route, especially if your map is esri/arcgis